# Node.js Path module source two regular express

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am confused with 2 regex in the node.js path module source

```
// Regex to split a windows path into three parts: [*, device, slash,
// tail] windows-only
var splitDeviceRe =
    /^([a-zA-Z]:|[\\\/]{2}[^\\\/]+[\\\/]+[^\\\/]+)?([\\\/])?([\s\S]*?)$/;

// Regex to split the tail part of the above into [*, dir, basename, ext]
var splitTailRe =
    /^([\s\S]*?)((?:\.{1,2}|[^\\\/]+?|)(\.[^.\/\\]*|))(?:[\\\/]*)$/;
```

How dose splitTailRe work? most confused with the group:
    `"((?:\.{1,2}|[^\\\/]+?|)(\.[^.\/\\]*|))"`

Comment: Explanation of the `splitTailRe` regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/eA1uF1/1). (Further reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.)

Comment: Or [regexper](https://regexper.com/#%5E(%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%3F)((%3F%3A%5C.%7B1%2C2%7D%7C%5B%5E%5C%5C%5C%2F%5D%2B%3F%7C)(%5C.%5B%5E.%5C%2F%5C%5C%5D*%7C))(%3F%3A%5B%5C%5C%5C%2F%5D*)%24) is pretty good. If you still don't understand, I don't mind submitting an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some help to you

splitDeviceRE = https://regex101.com/r/mV5gS0/2

splitTailRe = https://regex101.com/r/mV5gS0/1

It breaks down the regex you feed it and explains step by step what each 'section' of Regex is doing.